# How to take the output of sed to a variable beside other parameters?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sh

I have a sed command to take the first line of a file. I need to store that line in a variable without printing the line to the screen as sed does.
Here is my command:

```
sed  '1q;d' "../dbs/$1/$2"
```